# How to make moving CSS objects like this?

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

I am trying to make similar CSS animation like this website has in first block https://www.xeovo.com

How did they made clouds appear, it's not just an image, they have opacity.
Can you guys point me in right direction and give some links, that should be enough. Thanks.

*i tried to steal it and change images, but it didn't go well*

Comment: They are using CSS animations creating an `@keyframes` for each cloud. They animate the `opacity` in and change its `right` positioning to move it from right to left. If you `view-source` and look for the `.clouds` DIV it's all there.

Comment: @hungerstar thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [github](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for any animation. There is predefined class in that.